# ng-click on firing on mobile or tablet devices

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

On page load i have a controller that calls a service and then binds the returned data to some $scope.objects:

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $http, serviceGetData) {

    serviceGetData.getData(function(data) {
        $scope.LoginCount = data.LoginCount;
        $scope.ProductInfo = data.ProductInfo;
        $scope.ProfileInfo = data.ProfileInfo;

        // Delayed binding
        $scope.OrderHistory  = { History: [] };
    }

    $scope.populateModel = function(model, values) {
        var isArray = $.isArray(values);

        $.each(values, function(key, value) {

            if (isArray) {
                key = this.key;
               value = this.value;
            }

            if (model[key] !== value) {
                model[key] = value;
            }

        });
    };
}
```

And in my HTML, i try to bind $scope.OrderHistory by:

```
<h1><a href="#" ng-click="populateModel(OrderHistory  , { History: OrderEntries })" >View order details</a></h1>
```

This is fine when viewing on laptops/desktops, but not working in tablet and mobile devices e.g. iphone/ipad

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to [add the ngTouch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch). From documentation:

> A more powerful replacement for the default `ngClick` designed to be used on touchscreen devices. Most mobile browsers wait about 300ms after a tap-and-release before sending the click event. This version handles them immediately, and then prevents the following click event from propagating.
>
> **Requires the `ngTouch` module to be installed.**

Comment: I read about ngTouch, i would prefer not to have to import another library in my project.

Comment: @OamPsy, it's not another library, just external module for angular

Comment: Ah i see, are there any how-to's or example projects around?

Comment: Imported ngTouch into my project and seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

I tried adding the `ngTouch` library and dependency, but was still having a problem.

My *static* `<div>` elements which contained an `ng-click` worked fine, but the div's which were created dynamically (in an `ng-repeat` on the same webpage) which contained an `ng-click` didn't work.  Tapping on them just didn't do anything.

This happened on my iPhone 6, my iPad and in Google Chrome when I asked to view my webpage on any of the device types.  When I viewed the same webpage in IE or regular Chrome, all of the `ng-click`s worked fine.

The solution was to use the `ngMobileClick` directive [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34579185/391605) and changing my `ng-click`'s to `ng-mobile-click`.

After doing that, my dynamically created click events *did* get triggered normally when I tapped on them on a device.

Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue where the ng-click inside of a ng-repeat would not trigger.
I fixed this by adding [$event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Ex:

```
<li ng-repeat="option in $scope.options">
   <span><a ng-click="trigger(); $event.stopPropagation()"></a></span>
</li>
```