# Angular ng-click issues on Safari with IOS 8.3

Tags: ios, iphone, angularjs, safari, angularjs-ng-click

This is a weird issue, that is some what hard to generate and explore.

While building a web-app using Angular, my boss found that all the buttons on the app that are using `ng-click` directive are not working.

Now, this issue only happens on `iphone 6 with IOS 8.3 and using the safari browser`.

I can say that when was tested on iPhone5 (All versions), iPhone 6 (IOS 9), Safari for windows and all other browsers (Mobile and desktop), `ng-click` works like a charm.

The app is being build using `Angular 1.4.3`.

This is the code for the button, as you can see, nothing special about it:

```
<button class="btn calculate-button" ng-click="onCalculate()">Calculate</button>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.onCalculate = function () {
     //Do something... And then:
     $state.go('someplace');
};
```

I tried many changes that were suggested here, including `ng-touch`, `ng-bind`, building my own click directive as follows:

```
.directive('basicClick', function($parse, $rootScope) {
    return {
        compile: function(elem, attr) {
            var fn = $parse(attr.basicClick);
            return function(scope, elem) {
                elem.on('click', function(e) {
                    fn(scope, {$event: e});
                    scope.$apply();
                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Couldn't find any proper solution for the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed it in the end.

The problem was in the `//Do something... And then:` part of the function.
At some point along the way, that function saves some data to the browser local storage.

My boss was using private browsing on safari, and apparently when using private browsing on safari, the browser wont save and data on the local storage and it throws an exception and kills the code.

Well, thanks any way.

Answer (score 22):

IOS 8.4.1 Update has a known issue which stop ng-link and ng-click to work.

Using "touchstart click" can possibly solve this issue.

```
app.directive("ngMobileClick", [function () {
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind("touchstart click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            scope.$apply(attrs["ngMobileClick"]);
        });
    }
}])
```

HTML call: `ng-mobile-click="onCalculate()"`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it as soon as I can and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Found the solution. It wasn't that. Thanks any way!

Comment: This one worked for me, thanks. @Iamisti do you have a link to the known issue description or something like that?

Comment: Brilliant !  I had a webpage where static ng-clicks worked fine, but dynamically created (using an ng-repeat) DOM elements containing an ng-click just wouldn't trigger the click event, when the page was viewed on a device.  Using this Directive instead solved my issue - thank you !

Comment: This fixed an issue that I had on iOS, thanks! Same problem as @MikeGledhill