# trigger a spinner on an a tag

Tags: jquery, angularjs, spinner

I want to add a spinner to show something is happening because there is a delay between the user clicking on the call to action and the next page on a mobile with a slow connection. The code below works on desktop and under emulation in Chrome but not on an iOS device.

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/next-page"
   ng-click="showLoader();"
>Next Page</a>

<div id="loadScreen" class="load-screen" ng-show="displayLoader">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
</div>
```

In the controller

```
$scope.displayLoader = false;

$scope.showLoader = function(event) {
    $scope.displayLoader = true;
}
```

Is there a known issue with using ng-click on an anchor tag on mobile devices? What do I need to do to make this work? There is php logic within the href attribute on the actual code base, therefore, I am reluctant to move the URL into the controller.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575510/angular-ng-click-issues-on-safari-with-ios-8-3

Comment: @JamesHill - Thanks - this was the issue of the spinner not showing. Now I have to work on making it work for users in private mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location` inside your to navigate to your url and remove href tag from your anchor tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
.spinner {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<a ng-click="showLoader();">Next Page</a>
<div id="loadScreen" class="load-screen" ng-show="displayLoader">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
</div>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.displayLoader = false;
    $scope.showLoader = function(event) {
        $scope.displayLoader = true;
        window.location = "www.mysite.com/next-page";
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have lots of php logic to build a query string within the href. To refactor the code and move the query builder into the angular controller maybe as much effort as optimising the page to run faster which would remove the need for a spinner.