# angular ng-click handler is not called upon tapping on focused input on IPAD

Tags: angularjs, ipad, input, focus, angularjs-ng-click

I encountered the following problem with IPAD.

I have an input element with

> ng-click='someHandler()'

When input is blurred and i tap on it `someHandler` is called and input becomes focused as expected. However, when input is focused(and keypad is open) and i tap on it `someHandler` is not called, i.e. `ng-click` does not work. The same problem is there if i replace `ng-click` with `onclick`.

I can't find any information on the net how this can be solved.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using ng-focus instead? ng-click is typically not used as it conflicts with the focus and blur event.

Comment: that input is used as base element for `angular-bootstrap-colorpicker` so i have used `colorpicker="hex"` directive on that input. When input is not focused tapping on it opens the colorpicker popup under the input(you can choose color either from popup or by directly editing input value hex). Then when clicking on colorpicker popup color pallete the popup is closed and input field remains focused(also keypad is opened) and tapping on it again does not open the popup again.

Comment: Hm, complex stuff! Perhaps event.preventDefault() could help somewhere. Or maybe having ngclick on a containing div and make good use of event.stopPropagation(). Maybe try to replicate in a codepen/jsbin so we can have a play.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been tried with [ng-touch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch) check more at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25032394/5875039)

Comment: yes, `ng-touch` module is added as project dependency.