# How to enable ngClick with ngClickOverrideEnabled

Tags: angularjs, mobile, overriding

I am struggling for a while now with the simple task of instaling ngTouch and enabling ngClickOverride.

I am lost and I need help - my current code:

```
var app = angular.module('modulename', ['ngTouch']);

app.controller('ctrlName', function($scope, $http, $touch) {
      $touch.ngClickOverrideEnabled(true);}
```

while debugging I saw it went into the angular-touch.js, but went for the function:

```
this.$get = function() {
return {
  /**
   * @ngdoc method
   * @name  $touch#ngClickOverrideEnabled
   *
   * @returns {*} current value of `ngClickOverrideEnabled` set in the {@link ngTouch.$touchProvider $touchProvider},
   * i.e. if {@link ngTouch.ngClick ngTouch's ngClick} directive is enabled.
   *
   * @kind function
   */
  ngClickOverrideEnabled: function() {
    return ngClickOverrideEnabled;
  }
};
```

Instead of the function that actually enables the ngClick override

I am using AngularJS v1.5.8 - My main problem which I want to fix is that ng-click is not working on mobile and I based loads of actions on ng-click so I would really like to resolve this issue.

Comment: I think the following issues tells us that ng-click should work on mobile views, if you import ng-touch. you needn't override ngClick. Or am I missing something?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032237/ng-click-on-firing-on-mobile-or-tablet-devices

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to configure the $touchProvider like so

```
.config(['$touchProvider', function($touchProvider) {
    $touchProvider.ngClickOverrideEnabled(true);
}]);
```