# href inside a clickable div

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an angularJS clickable div

```
<div class="panel-heading" ng-click="wallet_to_bank = !wallet_to_bank">

  <span class="help-block pull-right">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/"></a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Everything works fine on a desktop, but the mobile version doesn't work.

any idea ?

Comment: the click is in the `<div>` or in the link inside ?

Comment: It won't help that the HTML is malformed (an unmatched `</i>` end-tag) and the div probably has no height (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-click on firing on mobile or tablet devices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25032394/2435473)

Comment: The </i> does not have an open tag but I tested this and it worked for me, but I didn't include the </i>

Comment: the missing <i> was just a copy and paste error, but thanks for the heads-up.  @PankajParkar I'll have a look at this

Comment: @MichaelWarner did you test this on mobile or tablet ?

Comment: Yes I got it working on my iPhone. I agree about the possible dup.